# Is it possible to apply a texture inside a GL_LINE_LOOP?

Tags: box2d, opengl-es

I am creating a game using Box2D and OpenGL ES 1.1.

I am taking the `b2PolygonShape` vertices and converting them into an OpenGL ES 1.1 `GL_LINE_LOOP`. The debugging view looks great, but now I want to apply textures to the **inside** of the line loop.

Is this possible? I used line loop instead of triangles because I am not sure how to handle complex polygons using triangles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Only rendered primitives get rasterized and shaded, and when you render using `GL_LINE_LOOP` your primitives are just the lines themselves, not the area enclosed by the lines.

If you want to rasterize and shade the area within the line, you have to render using a solid primitive like GL_TRIANGLES. If you have complex polygons you will first need to break them down into triangles using some kind of [triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) technique (you can also [search this site for other questions about polygon triangulation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=triangulate%20a%20polygon) if you get stuck).

Comment: shouldn't (a convex) line loop be trivially convertible to triangle fan?

Comment: If its convex, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old, but I just had exactly the same question ...

And now I found out that everything works fine if one replaces `GL_LINE_LOOP` by `GL_POLYGON`. Nevertheless you have to consider the fact that the tesselation solution is much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for answer, however the questions says "inside a `GL_LINE_LOOP`" and your answer is not to use `GL_LINE_LOOP`. The answer is clearly no, since `GL_LINE_LOOP` does not render anything except from the edges of an object.

Comment: By the way: An other problem are concave polygons.